# How can i prevent the default selection tooltip in react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

### Basic description

I'm rendering an epub file in the webview and i want to the user can't be able to copy a text but i want to let him select the text for some reasons (Highlight and some stuff)

.

#### default tooptip :

[image: This is what the default tooltip looks like]

I just wanted to disable this default tooltip and don't show it after any selection .

I was searching and found i could stop user from selecting by using this 2 lines of code :

```css
"-webkit-user-select": "none",
"user-select": "none",
```

but this is not what i wanted . i want to let the user select the text and don't let them copy it .
.

Please Help Me Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the following npm module: https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text

Comment: @Atef I saw it but you can't make a customized box for it, you can just change the items name .